# How to implement "not in" predicate in Ebean?

Tags: java, ebean

I have a list that contains some ids I want my ebean query to exclude those ids. So basically I need to use "not in" predicate in the ebean just like sql has but unfortunately can not find that. Is there any other way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `not` expression, which can contain the `in` expression:

```
Ebean.find(MyClass.class).where()
  .not(Expr.in("id", new Long[]{1L,2L,3L})).findList();
```